# SSL connection with unsigned certificate

Tags: iphone, ssl, xamarin.ios, certificate, ios-simulator

I am running into the following problem with an iOS app we are developing. On my server I am running  a WCF-service. This service is running in HTTPS. I wrote a small test program to see if I can connect to it from another PC:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

Console.WriteLine("Press key to start webrequest");
Console.ReadKey();

WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("https://<serveraddress.here.com>");
Stream stream = wr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd());

Console.ReadKey();
```

This works as expected and returns html-code. Notice we're using `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to ensure that the certificate is being trusted in any case.

The same code in MonoTouch on the iPhone however returns the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException has been thrown
Error getting response stream (Write: BeginWrite failure): SendFailure
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Connecting to another a signed https site (paypal for example) works without problems. Also connecting to the server without https (regular http) works fine.

It seems like it's ignoring the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` and failing somewhere. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Catch WebException and get more detailed message. Maybe it has nothing to do with SSL or maybe detailed message will help indicate why SSL fails.

Comment: I hope the intention is to replace the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` function with something that checks e.g. certificate fingerprint values against a list that you know work?

Comment: The idea is to get a signed certificate in time. For testing purposes the validationcallback is used.

Comment: I have used the same approach successfully in Monotouch, so unless it broke in a recent MT release I don't really see a problem. Can you check your server logs if the app really reaches your server and what your server responds?

Comment: Yes, however that doesn't change the fact that this should work :)

The WebException doesn't give more info by the way. (As answer to comment below).

2

Comment: @Krumelur: The WCF is not hosted in ISS but in WCF Service Host. I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think there are logs available. I know however that I could connect them before hosting it as HTTPS and that I can reach the same address through the Safari browser of the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

> SSL connection with unsigned certificate

I suspect you're using a **self-signed** (not an **unsigned**) certificate that you made yourself (e.g. `makecert`) for temporary use.

Like others said in comments, this should work as **many** people are doing similar things when developing their applications.

> It seems like he's ignoring the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` and failing somwhere. Is there any way to fix this?

Mono (and MonoTouch) supports both the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` and the older `ICertificatePolicy` methods to allow application to have the *last* word on accepting (or refusing) an X.509 certificate. You can try the other method - but I'm not sure that's the issue.

You can also compare your (full, not partial) stack trace with the same code where `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is commented. If the error is **identical** then it's likely certificate related, otherwise it's not (there's a lot more that can go wrong with SSL/TLS ;-)

Sadly I can't give you more specific help because your question lacks important details.

- What version of MonoTouch are you using ?
- The full stack trace of the exception MonoTouch gives you ? from the partial one you gave it's not 100% clear that the issue happens when certificates are validated.
- Where/how did you execute your sample code ? e.g. was it on Mono or Microsoft .NET ? which version ?

I suggest you to open a bug report on http://bugzilla.xamarin.com (and include the missing details) since it's likely that we'll require even more data (e.g. a [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) log of the SSL communication).